# Sharing data with component of another module in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

just began to work with Angular 8.
I'm currently experimenting with creating an user interface for an complex project.

The Top Navigation Bar should represent the current mode the user is in. (Like Backend Operations, or Support System, ... which could represent optionally a different Modul).

I'm trying to implement everything in its own module as they could be developed by independent teams (in the future). So I moved everything on the design to the app component. (Layout) while the services that are shared between modules reside in an shared module.

This is the part that would reflect one first shared service property:

template:

```
<nav class="topBar navbar default-layout col-lg-12 p-0 fixed-top d-flex flex-row {{ getLocation() }}">
...
</nav>
```

component.ts

```
...
constructor(private frameworkService:FrameworkService) {
  this.fms = frameworkService;
  ...
}
  public getLocation(){
    return this.fms.getLocation();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

shared modules:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {FrameworkService} from "./services/framework/framework.service";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    FrameworkService
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {
}
```

framework.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class FrameworkService {
  private _location:string = '';

  getLocation(): string {
    console.log('getter');
    console.log(this._location);
    return this._location;
  }

  setLocation(value: string) {
    this._location = value;
    console.log('setter');
    console.log(value);
    console.log(this._location);
  }

  constructor() {
    this._location = 'bg-backend';
  }
}
```

in an module I'm trying to call it like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { BackendRoutingModule } from './backend-routing.module';
import {MainComponent} from "./main/main.component";
import {SharedModule} from "../shared/shared.module";
import {FrameworkService} from "../shared/services/framework/framework.service";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BackendRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class BackendModule {
  constructor(FrameworkService: FrameworkService){
    FrameworkService.setLocation('bg-backend');
  }
}
```

As far as I can see, I'm running into the problem that it is not using a singleton pattern (as I would have expected it) but more a multi instance approach. Who can I fix this. Several of the pages I looked at didn't really help me or just simply confused me. What I currently also jet need to find out is who to set the value depending on the active module.
Any help is appreciated

:-)

Chris

Comment: The most simplest solution for this i would suggest is.. Registering this service with the root module and then inject in any other module that requires to access.. As it will be available for all the modules for access and you wont run into this issue.. Even with your current approach you will have to export it and with forRoot.. this link might help https://medium.com/slackernoon/when-to-use-angulars-forroot-method-400094a0ebb7

Comment: Try this: https://therichpost.com/how-to-share-data-between-two-components-in-angular-7

Comment: That you for all the tips. I went with the second approach that now works.

Comment: The shared elements are now working. But how do I get the location to only update if one of the components of the service one are accessed.
I don't want to call it on every request manually within an component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it didn't work as expected.
I figured out that each session opens an new instance of this service.
So what I did is to store the required informations in the localstorage and accessing it in an static manor.

thanks for you help :-)